# store data from an api to mysql node

Tags: mysql, node.js, express

I am trying to store data from an api to mysql,    and I am getting    an error

here is the code :

```
(async () => {
  let arr = [];

  try {
    const response = await fetch('https://restcountries.com/v3.1/all');
    const json = await response.json();

    json.forEach((element) => {
      let obj = {
        cca2: element.cca2,
        ccn3: element.ccn3,
        cca3: element.cca3,
        region: element.region,
        latlng: element.latlng,
      };
      arr.push(obj);
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
  console.log(arr);

  db.query('INSERT INTO countries (`cca2,ccn3,cca3,region,latlng`) values ?', [
    arr.map((item) => [
      item.cca2,
      item.ccn3,
      item.cca3,
      item.region,
      item.latlng,
    ]),
  ]);
})();
```

the error :  Unknown column 'cca2,ccn3,cca3,region,latlng' in 'field list'

Comment: Typo(s)?  You have a closing `)` with no opening `(`, and you have only one value placeholder when you're expecting 5 values...

Comment: Regarding the edit... Why did you add those back-ticks?  What do you think they're accomplishing and why are you specifically enclosing that content in them?  The question will forever be a moving target as long as you're just randomly typing text into your code.

Comment: hello david , thanks for answering , how do i make more than one placeholder ??

Comment: You can find many, many examples and tutorials by using your favorite search engine to find things like "node mysql insert example".  For example, where you have one placeholder: `?`  You can instead include five placeholders: `(?, ?, ?, ?, ?)`  Again, please refer to examples and tutorials instead of just making random changes to the code.

Answer (score 0):

You have an extra parenthesis in your query.

```js
db.query(`INSERT INTO countries (cca2,ccn3,cca3,region,latlng) values ?`, [
  arr.map((item) => [
    item.cca2,
    item.ccn3,
    item.cca3,
    item.region,
    item.latlng,
  ]),
]);
```

Comment: thanks , now I am getting another error 
 Unknown column 'cca2,ccn3,cca3,region,latlng' in 'field list'

Comment: It is either that those columns really do not exist in your table or it is a quotation problem. This article might be helpful https://sebhastian.com/mysql-unknown-column-field-list/.